# Default value for JavaScript function throws error in JS Fiddle

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, jsfiddle

I am trying to define a simple function such as:

```
function example(foo, bar = 'hello') {
    console.log(bar);
}

example('hi');
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/15mxehrx/) (see error in console when running):

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token '='. Expected a ')' or a ',' after a parameter declaration.

Though MDN describes this is not available in IE and Safari, it was my understanding that including Babel should allow ES 6 functionality, or is this a misunderstanding?

Comment: i don't get an error when I run your fiddle

Comment: Just for confirmation: as expected, this works nicely with Firefox, so the problem is not in your ES6 code.

Comment: i think yes transpiling your code with some transpiler will solve it.http://www.es6fiddle.net/isanhqlp/

Comment: How are you involving babel? What's your `.babelrc` look like? Babel without plugins doesn't transform anything.

Comment: i don't get an error when I run your fiddle

Comment: Goodness, @RafiUdDaulaRefat and Jacob one of those days, of course, I had to setup my build system to transpile properly, in this case, brunch with babel-brunch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just including `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.13.2/babel.min.js` (babel-standalone) as a script is not enough. You either have to use a script tag with type `text/babel`, or use the Babel API to compile your code (`Babel.transform()`). See [Usage in babel-standalone GitHub page](https://github.com/Daniel15/babel-standalone#usage).

However, JS Fiddle provides an easier way to use Babel. Just click on "JavaScript" in the top right corner, and choose Babel as language.

See [corrected JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/15mxehrx/3/).

Answer (score 1):

look at this. your code was not transpiling properly.

```
<script type="text/babel">
function example(foo, bar = 'hello') {
    console.log(bar);
}

example('hi');
</script>
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Refatrafi/15mxehrx/2/